# Kiymd - Python app crashes on mobile phone

Tags: python, android, crash, mobile-application, kivymd

Good morning,

i'm very new on kivymd and Python, too. I made a code for a mobile app. Below the main.py code used to build the application. When i create the APK file using Colab - Buildozer (below the buildozer.spec file) and after installing the app on the phone, it correctly open in its main window but when i click to go in the second window where some actions could be done, it crashes.. The same app works perfectly on the pc, using PyCharm.

If i have to provide some other informations, please ask.

Thank you.

**MAIN.PY**

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton, MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

class MainWindow(Screen):

    #Window.size = (480, 700)
    start_application=ObjectProperty(None)



class ShoppingWindow(Screen):
    #Window.size = (480, 700)
    fruit_vegetables_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    fruit_vegetables_Okbutton=ObjectProperty(None)
    bread_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    bread_OKButton=ObjectProperty(None)
    pasta_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    pasta_OKButton=ObjectProperty(None)
    delete_cart=ObjectProperty(None)
    delete_veg_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    delete_bread_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    delete_pasta_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    cleanser_Okbutton=ObjectProperty(None)
    delete_cleanser_value = ObjectProperty(None)
    fish_Okbutton=ObjectProperty(None)
    delete_fish_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    fish_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    meat_Okbutton=ObjectProperty(None)
    meat_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    delete_meat_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    freezer_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    freezer_Okbutton=ObjectProperty(None)
    delete_freezer_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    cheese_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    cheese_Okbutton=ObjectProperty(None)
    delete_cheese_value=ObjectProperty(None)
    cookies_value = ObjectProperty(None)
    cookies_Okbutton = ObjectProperty(None)
    delete_cookies_value = ObjectProperty(None)

    def fruit_vegetables(self):
        data_file = open("data_file.txt", "a+")
        data_file.write(self.fruit_vegetables_value.text+'\n')
    def bread(self):
        global entry
        entry=1
        data_file = open("data_file.txt", "a+")
        data_file.write(self.bread_value.text + '\n')
    def pasta(self):
        data_file = open("data_file.txt", "a+")
        data_file.write(self.pasta_value.text + '\n')
    def cleanser(self):
        data_file = open("data_file.txt", "a+")
        data_file.write(self.cleanser_value.text + '\n')
    def fish(self):
        data_file = open("data_file.txt", "a+")
        data_file.write(self.fish_value.text + '\n')
    def meat(self):
        data_file = open("data_file.txt", "a+")
        data_file.write(self.meat_value.text + '\n')
    def freezer(self):
        data_file = open("data_file.txt", "a+")
        data_file.write(self.freezer_value.text + '\n')
    def cheese(self):
        data_file = open("data_file.txt", "a+")
        data_file.write(self.cheese_value.text + '\n')
    def cookies(self):
        data_file = open("data_file.txt", "a+")
        data_file.write(self.cookies_value.text + '\n')
    def delete_veg_value_func(self):
        self.fruit_vegetables_value.text=""
    def delete_cookies_value_func(self):
        self.fruit_vegetables_value.text=""
    def delete_bread_value_func(self):
        self.bread_value.text=""
    def delete_pasta_value_func(self):
        self.pasta_value.text=""
    def delete_cleanser_value_func(self):
        self.cleanser_value.text=""
    def delete_fish_value_func(self):
        self.fish_value.text=""
    def delete_meat_value_func(self):
        self.meat_value.text=""
    def delete_freezer_value_func(self):
        self.freezer_value.text=""
    def delete_cheese_value_func(self):
        self.cheese_value.text=""



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm=ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name="MainWindow"))
sm.add_widget(ShoppingWindow(name="ShoppingWindow"))

class CartShow(OneLineListItem):
    pass

class CartWindow(Screen):
    scroll=ObjectProperty(None)
    refresh=ObjectProperty(None)
    back_to_home=ObjectProperty(None)
    refresh_cart=ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_enter(self):
        global x
        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            text="Click on an item to remove it from list and confirm with refresh!",
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text="OK",
                    theme_text_color="Custom",
                    text_color="black",
                    on_release=lambda _: self.dialog.dismiss())
            ]
        )

        self.dialog.open()
        with open("data_file.txt", 'r') as fp:
            x = len(fp.readlines())

    def refresh(self):

        with open("data_file.txt", 'r') as fp:
            q = len(fp.readlines())

            self.ids.scroll.clear_widgets()


            file= open("data_file.txt" , "r")
            i=0
            for line in file:
                i=i+1
                icons = list(md_icons.keys())
                self.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                    CartShow(text=f"{line}",on_release=self.erase_list_item))


    def erase_list_item(self,OneLineListItem):

        with open("data_file.txt", "r+") as f:
            d = f.readlines()
            f.seek(0)
            for k in d:
                if k != OneLineListItem.text:
                    f.write(k)
            f.truncate()

        self.ids.scroll.clear_widgets()

        file = open("data_file.txt", "r")
        i = 0
        for line in file:
            i = i + 1
            self.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                CartShow(text=f"{line}",on_release=self.erase_list_item))



class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        ww = Builder.load_file("Layout.kv")
        return ww
        return sm

MainApp().run()
```

**buildozer.spec - the part where i did some modifications**

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,txt,gif

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd,pillow

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.1.0
```

I tried to:

1. Modify specifications in buildozer file but no improvement was obtained
2. Make a debugging of the application but no improvement was obtained
3. Reading everywhere on the internet but no answer was found.

Comment: While `return`ing twice (with same indentation level and without any control statement) in python, only the first one is counted.

Comment: Thank you! but if that was the problem, the application wouldn't work on the PC. Right?

Comment: Not sure unless seeing the actual implementation.

Comment: Both on the PC and on mobile phone, the first window called “MainWindow” works. Then, when i tap somewhere on the screen (i used on_touch_down) on the PC the second window opens, but on the mobile it crashes….